# Javascript functions firing multiple times

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a trivia quiz with Javascript functions. Each question references some globally defined functions; "right" and "wrong" These are supposed to add points to the score. However, as I go through the quiz, it is listening to the previous question function's right and wrong functions. I have tried a multitude of fixes with no help. My tutor and I scratched our heads on it for a couple hours, so now I find myself here.

We both thought that if the event listeners were wrapped in curly brackets, they shouldn't be listening to clicks from other functions...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!

**Note:** The third and fourth question functions use the original format that I tried for the first and second questions.

```js
var timeEl = document.querySelector(".time");
var mainEl = document.getElementById("main");

var A = document.getElementById("A");
var B = document.getElementById("B");
var C = document.getElementById("C");
var D = document.getElementById("D");

var textA = document.querySelector(".textA");
var textB = document.querySelector(".textB");
var textC = document.querySelector(".textC");
var textD = document.querySelector(".textD");

var points = 0;

var secondsLeft = 60;

function setTime() {
  var timerInterval = setInterval(function() {
    secondsLeft--;
    timeEl.textContent = "Time: " + secondsLeft;

    if (secondsLeft === 0) {
      clearInterval(timerInterval);
      changePage();
    }

  }, 1000);
}

function changePage() {
  window.location.href = "./ending.html";
}

function wrong() {
  var anResult = document.getElementById("answer-result");
  anResult.textContent = "Wrong! -10 Points! :("
  points = points - 10;
  console.log(points)
}

function right() {
  var anResult = document.getElementById("answer-result");
  anResult.textContent = "Right! +10 Points! :)"
  points = points + 10;
  console.log(points)
}

setTime();
firstQuestion();

function q1CorrectClick() {
  right();
  secondQuestion();
  console.log("A")
}

function q1WrongClick() {
  wrong();
  secondQuestion();
}

function q2CorrectClick() {
  right();
  thirdQuestion();
}

function q2WrongClick() {
  wrong();
  thirdQuestion();
}

function firstQuestion() {
  var question = document.getElementById("question");
  A.addEventListener("click", q1WrongClick)
  // wrong()
  // secondQuestion()
  // console.log("A")
  // // A.removeEventListener();
  // };
  B.addEventListener("click", q1WrongClick)
  //   wrong()
  //   secondQuestion()
  //   console.log("B") this function will fire in the subsequent questionFunctions 
  //   // B.removeEventListener();
  // });
  C.addEventListener("click", q1WrongClick)
  //   wrong()
  //   secondQuestion()
  //   console.log("C")
  //   // C.removeEventListener();
  // });
  D.addEventListener("click", q1CorrectClick)
  //   right()
  //   secondQuestion()
  //   console.log("D")
  //   // D.removeEventListener();
  // });

  question.textContent = "What is the best selling car of all time?";

  textA.textContent = "Toyota Camry";
  textB.textContent = "Ford F-150";
  textC.textContent = "Honda Civic";
  textD.textContent = "Toyota Corolla";
  // the right answer! 
}

function secondQuestion() {
  var question = document.getElementById("question");
  A.addEventListener("click", q2WrongClick)
  //   wrong()
  //   thirdQuestion()
  // });
  B.addEventListener("click", q2CorrectClick)
  //   right()
  //   thirdQuestion()
  // });
  C.addEventListener("click", q2WrongClick)
  //   wrong()
  //   thirdQuestion()
  // });
  D.addEventListener("click", q2WrongClick)
  //   wrong()
  //   thirdQuestion()
  // });
  question.textContent = "First introduced in 1974, which iconic hatchback still remains popular today?";

  textA.textContent = "Ford Mustang";
  textB.textContent = "Volkswagen Golf";
  textC.textContent = "Toyota Celica";
  textD.textContent = "Fiat 500";

  // document.getElementById("quiz-body").removeEventListener("mouseover", firstQuestion); this didn't work. console.log functions still working from previous function.
}

function thirdQuestion() {
  var question = document.getElementById("question");
  A.addEventListener("click", function() {
    wrong()
    fourthQuestion()
  });
  B.addEventListener("click", function() {
    wrong()
    fourthQuestion()
  });
  C.addEventListener("click", function() {
    right()
    fourthQuestion()
  });
  D.addEventListener("click", function() {
    wrong()
    fourthQuestion()
  });
  question.textContent = "What is the world's fastest production car as of July 2020?";

  textA.textContent = "Koenigsegg Agera RS";
  textB.textContent = "Hennessy Venom GT";
  textC.textContent = "Buggatti Chiron Super Sport";
  textD.textContent = "Lamborghini Aventador";
}

function fourthQuestion() {
  var question = document.getElementById("question");
  A.addEventListener("click", function() {
    right()
    fifthQuestion()
  });
  B.addEventListener("click", function() {
    wrong()
    fifthQuestion()
  });
  C.addEventListener("click", function() {
    wrong()
    fifthQuestion()
  });
  D.addEventListener("click", function() {
    wrong()
    fifthQuestion()
  });
  question.textContent = "What 70s car is known for its suicide doors and convertible top?";

  textA.textContent = "Lincoln Continental";
  textB.textContent = "Buick Rivera";
  textC.textContent = "Ford Thunderbird";
  textD.textContent = "Oldsmobile Toronado";
}
```

```html
<div class="time"></div>
<div id="main">
  <div id="question"></div>
  <div>
    <input id="A" type="radio" name="choice" />
    <label class="textA"></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="B" type="radio" name="choice" />
    <label class="textB"></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="C" type="radio" name="choice" />
    <label class="textC"></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="D" type="radio" name="choice" />
    <label class="textD"></label>
  </div>
  <div id="answer-result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: After the first question, you need to clear the event listeners. Otherwise, each option still calls the function from the previous question when clicked.

Comment: I see a lot of places where you can use an array or loop...

Comment: I added HTML to make it run, fix if you need it to look the way you have it.

Comment: you don't need addEventListener for this type of app. just use onClick

Comment: @Rick, that is not such a good advise. there are good reasons to prefer `addEventListener` over `onclick`

Answer (score 0):

You never remove the click handlers from the previous question, but only add new handlers.

I would suggest a different approach. One where you don't change click handlers at all. The idea is that you don't encode the question and answers as *code*, but as *data*. This way you avoid also code repetition.

So first define a data structure in which you have all your questions, the answers, and the right answer. For instance:

```
var questions = [{ 
    question: "What is the best selling car of all time?", 
    answers: ["Toyota Camry", "Ford F-150", "Honda Civic", "Toyota Corolla"],
    correct: 3 // note: first answer has number 0
}, { 
    question: "First introduced in 1974, which iconic hatchback still remains popular today?",
    answers: ["Ford Mustang", "Volkswagen Golf", "Toyota Celica", "Fiat 500"],
    correct: 1
}, {
    question: "What is the world's fastest production car as of July 2020?",
    answers: ["Koenigsegg Agera RS", "Hennessy Venom GT", "Buggatti Chiron Super Sport", "Lamborghini Aventador"],
    correct: 2
}, { 
    question: "What 70s car is known for its suicide doors and convertible top?",
    answers: ["Lincoln Continental", "Buick Rivera", "Ford Thunderbird", "Oldsmobile Toronado"],
    correct: 0
}];
```

Now the only thing that needs to change from going to one question to the next is... the index in that array: it should move from 0 to 1, ...2, and finally 3.

All the rest you need to know about a certain question is then available at that index.

I would also suggest that you allow the user some time to see the result of their answer before displaying the next question. It can be confusing to see the new question with a "Correct" message below, while the new question was not answered yet.

Here is an implementation with just one click handler: one that deals with all four buttons.

```js
var timeEl = document.querySelector(".time");

var question = document.getElementById("question");
var answerButtons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".answer"));
var answerTexts = document.querySelectorAll(".text");
var anResult = document.getElementById("answer-result");
var score = document.getElementById("score");

var points = 0;
var secondsLeft = 60;

function setTime() {
  var timerInterval = setInterval(function() {
    secondsLeft--;
    timeEl.textContent = secondsLeft;

    if(secondsLeft === 0) {
      clearInterval(timerInterval);
      changePage();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function changePage() {
  // Commented out for this demo only
  // window.location.href = "./ending.html";
}

function displayResult(isCorrect) {
    if (isCorrect) {
        points = points + 10;
        anResult.textContent = "Right! +10 Points! :)"
    } else {
        points = points - 10;
        anResult.textContent = "Wrong! -10 Points! :("
    }
    score.textContent = points
    enableButtons(false); // Prevent that user keeps clicking buttons
}

function enableButtons(on) {
    for (let button of answerButtons) {
        button.disabled = !on;
    }
}

setTime();

var questions = [{ 
    question: "What is the best selling car of all time?", 
    answers: ["Toyota Camry", "Ford F-150", "Honda Civic", "Toyota Corolla"],
    correct: 3 // note: first answer has number 0
}, { 
    question: "First introduced in 1974, which iconic hatchback still remains popular today?",
    answers: ["Ford Mustang", "Volkswagen Golf", "Toyota Celica", "Fiat 500"],
    correct: 1
}, {
    question: "What is the world's fastest production car as of July 2020?",
    answers: ["Koenigsegg Agera RS", "Hennessy Venom GT", "Buggatti Chiron Super Sport", "Lamborghini Aventador"],
    correct: 2
}, { 
    question: "What 70s car is known for its suicide doors and convertible top?",
    answers: ["Lincoln Continental", "Buick Rivera", "Ford Thunderbird", "Oldsmobile Toronado"],
    correct: 0
}];

var currentQuestion = 0;
displayQuestion();

document.addEventListener("click", function (e) { // One click handler for all four buttons
    let buttonNum = answerButtons.indexOf(e.target);
    if (buttonNum < 0) return; // This was not a click event on an answer button
    displayResult(buttonNum === questions[currentQuestion].correct);
    setTimeout(function () { // allow some time for the user to see the result
        currentQuestion++;
        if (currentQuestion >= questions.length) return changePage(); // Or whatever is suitable
        displayQuestion();
    }, 2000); 
});

function displayQuestion() {
    question.textContent = questions[currentQuestion].question;
    questions[currentQuestion].answers.forEach(function (answer, i) {
        answerTexts[i].textContent = answer;
    });
    enableButtons(true);
    anResult.textContent = ""
}
```

```html
Time: <span class="time">60</span><br>
Score: <span id="score">0</span><br>
<div id="question"></div>
<button class="answer">A</button> <span class="text"></span><br>
<button class="answer">B</button> <span class="text"></span><br>
<button class="answer">C</button> <span class="text"></span><br>
<button class="answer">D</button> <span class="text"></span><br>
<div id="answer-result"></div>
```